# SQL Server query for finding the sum of 4 consecutive values

Tags: sql-server-2005

Can somebody help me in finding the sum of 4 consecutive values i.e rolling sum of last 4 values.

Like:

```
VALUE   SUM
1   NULL
2   NULL
3   NULL
4   10
5   14
6   18
7   22
8   26
9   30
10  34
11  38
12  42
13  46
14  50
15  54
16  58
17  62
18  66
19  70
20  74
21  78
22  82
23  86
24  90
25  94
26  98
27  102
28  106
29  110
30  114
31  118
32  122
33  126
34  130
35  134
36  138
37  142
38  146
```

Thanks,

Comment: Do numbers *always* increment by 4?

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(select top 4 Value from [table] order by Value Desc)
```

or, perhaps

```
select sum(value)
from [Table]
where Value >= (Max(Value) - 4)
```

I haven't actually tried either of those- and can't at the moment, but they should get you pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ID can give you the last 4 rows.

```
SELECT SUM([SUM])
FROM
    (
    SELECT TOP 4 [SUM] FROM myTable ORDER BY ID DESC
    ) foo
```

Each time you query it, it will read the last 4 rows.

If this is wrong (e.g. you want the sum of each consecutive 4 rows), then please give sample output

Answer (score 0):

Quick attempt, which gets the results you've posted in your question (except the 1st 3 rows are not NULL). Assumes that VALUE field is unique and in ascending order:

```
-- Create test TABLE with 38 values in
DECLARE @T TABLE (Value INTEGER)
DECLARE @Counter INTEGER
SET @Counter = 1
WHILE (@Counter <= 38)
    BEGIN
        INSERT @T VALUES(@Counter)
        SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
    END

-- This gives the results   
SELECT t1.VALUE, x.Val
FROM @T t1
    OUTER APPLY(SELECT SUM(VALUE) FROM (SELECT TOP 4 VALUE FROM @T t2 WHERE t2.VALUE <= t1.VALUE ORDER BY t2.VALUE DESC) x) AS x(Val)
ORDER BY VALUE
```

At the very least, you should see the kind of direction I was heading in.

Answer (score 0):

Following would work if your `Value` column is sequential

```
;WITH q (Value) AS (
    SELECT  1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  q.Value + 1
    FROM    q
    WHERE   q.Value < 38
)

SELECT  q.Value
        , CASE WHEN q.Value >= 4 THEN q.Value * 4 - 6 ELSE NULL END
FROM    q
```

otherwise you might use something like this

```
;WITH q (Value) AS (
    SELECT  1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  q.Value + 1
    FROM    q
    WHERE   q.Value < 38
)
, Sequential (ID, Value) AS (
    SELECT  ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Value)
            , Value
    FROM    q
)
SELECT  s1.Value
        , [SUM] = s1.Value + s2.Value + s3.Value + s4.Value
FROM    Sequential s1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Sequential s2 ON s2.ID = s1.ID - 1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Sequential s3 ON s3.ID = s2.ID - 1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Sequential s4 ON s4.ID = s3.ID - 1
```

Note that the table `q`in the examples is a stub for your actual table. The actual statement then becomes

```
;WITH Sequential (ID, Value) AS (
    SELECT  ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Value)
            , Value
    FROM    YourTable
)
SELECT  s1.Value
        , [SUM] = s1.Value + s2.Value + s3.Value + s4.Value
FROM    Sequential s1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Sequential s2 ON s2.ID = s1.ID - 1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Sequential s3 ON s3.ID = s2.ID - 1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Sequential s4 ON s4.ID = s3.ID - 1
```